# Inserting an object into Mongo database using Scala's ReactiveMongo driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, play-reactivemongo

I am learning how to use Scala, MongoDB and the Play framework all together, and I have been looking at a demo project that's located here: https://github.com/jonasanso/play-reactive-mongo-db

However, I don't understand the syntax in the `create()` method. Is there another way of writing it without the use of the keyword `yield`? I'm still learning Scala and I don't understand how this method works.

```
  def create(name: String, population: Int) = Action.async {
    for {
      cities <- citiesFuture
      lastError <- cities.insert(City(name, population))
    } yield
      Ok("Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError))
  }
```

Comment: It's recommended to first read the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use for-yield syntax, you can translate your code to equivalent:

```
citiesFuture
  .flatMap (cities => cities.insert(City(name, population))
  .map (lastError => Ok(s"Mongo LastError: $lastError"))
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks for this! I was wondering can I replace `flatMap()` with `map()` or is there a specific reason to use `flatMap()`? I'm still getting to grips with understanding when to use one over the other.

Comment: You cannot use map here instead of flatMap because in this case you'll get Future[Future[String]]. To make chain of futures: first execute citiesFuture, than execute future.insert(...) you have to use flatMap. And finally for result of cities.insert you can use map to convert String result to Play's 'Ok'